# Data saved in Get request Success block can't be used

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking-3

My question is pretty simple and I'm sure it's solution is also simple but I just don't know and I can't find a solution online.

Here is my code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:@"http://api.dndzgz.com/services/bus" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
    //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    NSArray *locationsArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"locations"];

    for (NSDictionary *location in locationsArray) {
        NSString *stopId = [location objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *stopTitle = [location objectForKey:@"title"];
        CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        CLLocationDegrees longitude = [[location objectForKey:@"lon"] doubleValue];

        BusStop *stop = [[BusStop alloc] init];
        stop.name = stopTitle;
        stop.number = stopId;
        stop.latitude = latitude;
        stop.longitude = longitude;

        [self.stopsArray addObject: stop];
    }

} failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Basically the stopsArray is getting populated when I check it within the success block, but when I try to use it later, It's an empty array.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: where did you log self.stopsArray? after loop? where did you initialised it?

Comment: print the locationarray check it value is display ya not than after tell me

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray *stopsArray;
```

hope it helps.

Comment: when he used self.stopsArray he already declared it as a property.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

`self.stopsArray` is not a block variable.       You need to declare a block variable of array.  The correct code below:
1.`__block NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [NSMutableArray array];`    adding this line code above `AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];`
             2. `[tmpArray addObject: stop]; self.stopArray = tmpArray;`   replacing this line code `[self.stopsArray addObject: stop];`

Comment: well actually self.stopsArray will work since its an instance of the class. you only need to do __block if your array instance is within the same method as your block.

Comment: And then , add the following code:
`manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
        manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];`